# Sending email from Django via hosted SMTP

Tags: django, email, smtp, django-email

How do you send email from Django using a hosted SMTP account (specially on Namecheap)?

I thought this would be straight forward, and simply a matter of filling out the [standard EMAIL_* fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/) in my settings.py.

However, after entering my credentials in *both* my settings.py and Thunderbird, Thunderbird can download and send email, but Django times out with the error "SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed" when attempting to do the same.

My working settings in Thunderbird for my outgoing server (SMTP):

```
Server Name: oxmail.registrar-servers.com
Port: 465
User Name: myuser@mydomain.com
Authentication method: Normal password
Connection Security: SSL/TLS
```

My non-working settings in my Django settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'oxmail.registrar-servers.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myuser@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Aren't these settings identical? What am I doing wrong? Why does one work while the other fails?

Comment: Can you show an error message?

Answer (score 27):

Turns out the problem was that the default SMTP backend in Django **does not support SSL**, and my SMTP host required it (not just TLS). Fortunately, I found a [dirt-simple](https://github.com/bancek/django-smtp-ssl) SSL backend, added `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'` to my settings.py and everything just worked.

Comment: Can I give you more reputation points somehow ? This just saved my sanity trying to connect to namecheap's SMTP server.

Comment: over a year later it still works - I've just used it with Django 1.6.5

Comment: It is now EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
You may edit the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28075147/969984

Answer (score 8):

The settings below:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.yourdomain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-reply@yourdomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

worked for me. 
My django version I tested with is 1.8.8.