# Django send_mail fails in 1.7 Says no django_smtp_ssl

Tags: python, django

I'm porting some Django 1.5 to 1.7, and a send_mail() call is failing for me. I checked [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/) and they seem to suggest my syntax is still okay.

I tried in the Django shell mode, to get a trace to share here, and it still fails in the same manner. I'm simply calling send_mail() with:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Test mail', 'This is a test', 'addr@site.ca' ['addr2@site.ca'], fail_silently=False)
```

and I get a traceback with

```
ImportError: No module named django_smtp_ssl
```

Now, that smtp_ssl looks like from smtplib.  I tried importing smtplib along with send_mail, but that didn't help either.

In my settings.py, I have the usual PORT and HOST details and

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
```

Any suggestions?

-Thx, Ross.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing like putting together a question to help yourself find the answer.

Looks like the EMAIL_BACKEND location has changed in this version of Django.  So the answer (for others who google like me without finding the solution) is simply the updated backend pointer in your settings.py file.

It is now:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Cheers,
Ross.